# Docker: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:61615 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:61615

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use ActiveMQ in Docker, but I've started to get this error when starting the container.

```
Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 500) server error - Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:61613 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:61613: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

I could not find any service that is using these ports (maybe I looking in a wrong way).
I'm seeing that people generally suggest to restart `winnat`, but I am not sure if it's a good idea and I'd like to know if there are any other solutions to this problem.

Also changing ports ranges won't work in my case since they are already set to a suggested value:

```
Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
---------------------------------
Start Port      : 49152
Number of Ports : 16384
```

Here is a part of my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'
networks:
  test-net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.33.1.0/24

services:
  activemq:
    image: privat_artifactory
    container_name: test-activemq
    restart: always
    networks:
      - test-net
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"
      - "1883:1883"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61613-61616:61613-61616"
```

Comment: run `docker container ls -a`. ports may be reserved by stopped containers as well

Comment: I ran this command, but I don't see any stopped containers with this port.

Comment: `0.0.0.0:0` you try to expose port `0`? check again the command you are using

Comment: In fact, please update your question to show your complete `docker run` command line (or your `docker-compose.yaml` file if that's what you're using).

Comment: @Mihai, I am exposing port listen tcp 0.0.0.0:61613, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: yes @IhorVolkov that's the host part of it. what are you connecting it to inside the container?

Comment: @Mihai, I added a piece of my docker-compose file, I hope it will help to see what I am trying to do. The thing is that it worked before with the same yml file.

Comment: then maybe something changed on your host. try to remove the network configuration (maybe you updated docker and somehow it works on a different network config). It doen't look like the port is taken... If you are on Mac or windows check the resources settings for Docker Desktop

Comment: Use tcpview to show the ports used

Comment: Windows is the problem. Try with linux